# Repeater Itemdatabound with many usercontrols too slow

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater, itemdatabound

Hi I have created a web application in which I am facing a performance issue as I am binding 15 usercontrols inside a repeater on itemdatabound and i am using usercontrol's prerender event to bind data can you please suggest me any alternative to this

```
if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
{
    DataRowView row = e.Item.DataItem as DataRowView;
    HomePhought uxHomePhought = (HomePhought)e.Item.FindControl("uxHomePhought");
    HomeConnection uxHomeConnection = (HomeConnection)e.Item.FindControl("uxHomeConnection");
    HomeTestimonialPublished uxHomeTestimonial = (HomeTestimonialPublished)e.Item.FindControl("uxHomeTestimonial");
    HomeProfileEdit uxHomeProfileEdit = (HomeProfileEdit)e.Item.FindControl("uxHomeProfileEdit");
    HomeMemex uxHomeMemex = (HomeMemex)e.Item.FindControl("uxHomeMemex");
    HomeInterestMemex uxHomeInterestMemex = (HomeInterestMemex)e.Item.FindControl("uxHomeInterestMemex");
    HomeMemexPhought uxHomeMemexPhought = (HomeMemexPhought)e.Item.FindControl("uxHomeMemexPhought");
    //HomeBFFTips uxHomeBFFTip = (HomeBFFTips)e.Item.FindControl("uxHomeBFFTip");
    HomePageCreate uxHomePageCreate = (HomePageCreate)e.Item.FindControl("uxHomePageCreate");
    HomePageHiveFive uxHomePageHiveFive = (HomePageHiveFive)e.Item.FindControl("uxHomePageHiveFive");
    HomePageNewsAdd uxHomeBusinessNewsAdd = (HomePageNewsAdd)e.Item.FindControl("uxHomeBusinessNewsAdd");
    HomePageNewsComment uxHomePageNewsComment = (HomePageNewsComment)e.Item.FindControl("uxHomePageNewsComment");
    HomePageNewsHighFive uxHomePageNewsHighFive = (HomePageNewsHighFive)e.Item.FindControl("uxHomePageNewsHighFive");
    HomeMedalAchieved HomeMedalAchieved1 = (HomeMedalAchieved)e.Item.FindControl("HomeMedalAchieved1");

    ...................
    ...................
    //  Binding user controls
    ...................
    ...................

}
```

Comment: Can you post the code that you are using ?

Comment: Why are you using this method, why can't you directly use code like `<%# Eval("HomePhought") %>` for each data field inside item template?

Comment: @PrashantLakhlani: Why would that affect the speed? IMHO, using code-behind is cleaner and adheres more to Separation of Concerns.

Comment: What leads you to believe the performance problems are due to binding the UserControls? In my experience, most performance issues are related to other processes, such as data access. That being said, I don't believe there is another, "faster" way of doing that.

Comment: When you bind some dataSource to a repeater, you can directly use `<%# Eval("HomePhought") %>` inside ItemTemplate. That will reduce control tree and view state of the application. Why are you binding data in `ItemDatabound` is an important question

Comment: @PrashantLakhlani: `Eval` uses reflection, which is inherently slower. You can always do this: `<%# ((DataRowView)Container.DataItem).SOMEPROPERTY%>`. But again I doubt there is a significant performance difference between that and OnItemDataBound.